# C# Null-conditional operator expansion

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, expansion

How exactly is null conditional operator expaned in C# 6? Could someone explain it as it is [Curious C# using statement expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946999/curious-c-sharp-using-statement-expansion) expanded in the question?

The description from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) is as follows:

> If one operation in a chain of conditional member access and index
>   operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s execution stops.

Few working examples:

```
a) int count = aClassInstance?.PropertyCollection?.Count ?? 0;
b) if (aClassInstance?.PropertyCollection?.Count > 0)
c) aClassInstance?.Dispose();
d) if (aClassInstance?.PropertyCollection?[0]?.Foo == "bar")
```

Comment: `myEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs())` will access `myEvent` only once.

Comment: Thanks for linking the duplicate, I haven't found it. @Gabriel, I'll made another, separated question about those two cases.